# Exec(Linux). How it functions internally? Linux executable attributes(rlimit)

Tags: android, linker, linux-kernel, filesystems, exec

I would like to understand what is rlimit and pipe limit for an executable?
I am debugging an issue where dynamically built executables are crashing while loaded but statically built executables are fine.
WHen a dynamically built executable is loaded,

I see the following prints after the register dump

```
Process 2748(ls) has RLIMIT_CORE set to 1
Aborting Core
```

First of all some one please explain what is rlimit with perspective to exec. Also is there some thing called pipe limit? I see this proc entry.

Please point me to some resource that explains these attributes of an executable.

**Question 2 :**
When an executable is loaded, what exactly exec does? linker will load the shared libraries that are needed by my executable. So for this to happen linker(a binary inside /system/bin) should execute first.

Hence I understand that linker(system/bin/linker) and executable(ls) both are loaded by exec. Is my understanding correct? This is all theory. If someone, probably who is good at both fs and proc management, could point me to the relevant source, it would be great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RLIMIT_CORE` is used to place a limit on the amount of info that coredump is allowed to produce, before it is aborted. Once this limit is hit, no more info is logged and the message `Aborting Core` is logged to the console.

From the man page of **[core](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html)** :

> A process can set its soft **`RLIMIT_CORE`** resource limit to place an upper limit on the size of the core dump file that will be produced if it receives a "core dump" signal.

Use [`setrlimit()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) to configure `RLIMIT_CORE` to a larger value to obtain complete coredumps.

---

The most common format of executables/shared-objects is **ELF**. On Linux, the dynamic loading and linking of these shared-objects is performed by **[`ld.so`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html)**

**`ld.so`** is loaded in the address space of a newly created process (by **`exec`** in this case) and executed first. This is possible as its path is embedded into the `.interp` section of the executable binary during compilation.

The dynamic linker then

- loads the initial executable image
- loads the dependent shared-objects(`*.so` files)
- jumps to the entry-point of the executable

<sub>**Reference : [Dynamic linker on ELF-based Unix-like systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker#ELF-based_Unix-like_systems)**</sub>